# What does "quantum theory forbids promiscuous entanglements" mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, hawking-radiation, black-hole-firewall

The context is [this article](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/08/13/science/space/a-black-hole-mystery-wrapped-in-a-firewall-paradox.html) about black hole firewalls.  The phrase appears on page 3.  It appears to be saying that only pairs of particles can be entangled, never multiple particles, and that this is essential to the firewall paradox.

Of course any number of particles can be entangled, at least in the usual sense of the word.  Is Dr. Polchinski using the word in a specialized manner, or has the reporter just misunderstood or over-simplified?  If the issue isn't about entanglement, what is it about - something to do with the no-cloning theorem, perhaps?

Comment: http://www.quantiki.org/wiki/Monogamy_of_entanglement

Comment: @wsc's link refers only to qubits, which makes me wonder whether it's valid for things that have more than 2 states. Another source of "twoness" is that in the popularized cartoon of Hawking radiation, we have particle-antiparticle pairs created at the event horizon...?

Comment: Double entendre is the order of the day.

Comment: The criterion of monogamy seems to [depend on your chosen correlation measure](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.3967).  According to the reference, the usual entanglement measures are indeed monogamous.

Comment: There are 2 differents concepts. If you take $n$ particles, you could consider the global entanglement of the $n$ particles, or you could consider the (relative) entanglement of a subset of $m$ particles. For instance, the GHZ state $|000\rangle + |111\rangle$ is a maximally entangled state of $3$ particles, but if we look at the entanglement of $2$ particles among the $3$, we find that there is no entanglement (to see this, we may look at the reduced density matrix which is a diagonal matrix (so a classical probabilistic density matrix), so it does not represent an entangled state.

Comment: @Trimok: I think that answers my question, if you want to post it as an answer.

Comment: ... of course, it still leaves me wondering why the 4 particles involved have to be maximally entangled as pairs in multiple combinations.  I can see that the one pair of particles (entangled to one another) might need to be collectively entangled with the other pair of particles (also entangled to one another) but that doesn't obviously break the monogamy inequality.  However, at least I know what they mean now, even if it isn't obvious why.

Comment: Bonus question, if anyone wants to comment: since QM is inherently non-local, why would it be surprising that the event horizon is a special place once QM is taken into account?  (It seems obvious that if you're hovering just over the horizon, you could measure the distance to it by measuring the apparent temperature of the Hawking radiation.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston : Fist, the AMPS argument is certainly wrong, and some top physicists have shown this . However, in their argument, there are not 4 particles. There are only 3 "particles" or 3 d.o.f. (degrees of freedom). a) The outside near horizon  d.o.f. are entangled with the early Hawking radiation d.o.f.  b) The outside near horizon  d.o.f are entangled with the inside near horizon d.o.f. - So, you may use a baby model with 3 particles. Finally, QM is perfectly local, and you cannot transmit information instantaneously. Yes, QM modify horizon, you have a notion of "stretched" horizon.

Comment: (1) What happened to the entanglement between the early Hawking radiation and its pair inside the black hole? (2) If you use the Heisenberg picture pure QM is explicitly local, except during wavefunction collapse (which can't carry information, but must still makes the model non-local).  In this case since we're dealing with a thermal phenomena we're going to be using density matrices, isn't that equivalent to wavefunction collapse in terms of the locality of the model?